# How to combine data.tables by= with its shift() without having to create new variables?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to generate row sums of a variable and its lag(s). Say I have:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(id = rep(c("AT","DE"), each = 3),
                   time = rep(2001:2003, 2), var1 = c(1:6), var2 = c(NA, 1:3, NA, 8))
```

And I want to create a variable which adds 'var1' and the first lag of 'var2' by 'id'. If I create the lag first and the sum, I know how to:

```
data[ , lag := shift(var2, 1), by = id]
data[ , goalmessy := sum(var1, lag, na.rm = TRUE), by = 1:NROW(data)]
```

But is there a way to use `shift` inside `sum` or something similar (like apply sum or sth)? The intuitive problem I have, is that the by command is evaluated first as far as I know so we will be in a single row which makes the shifting unfeasible. Any hints?

Comment: I didn't get your comment

Comment: nevermind, just thought its better to stay away from as.data.frame... Still, there was no by= option there and the goal looked different, no? Where did the 0 in the first row come from?

Comment: A crude workaround is to replace NA with zero: `data[, new := var1 + replace(lag, is.na(lag), 0)]`. Avoiding `by=every_single_row` is a plus, by the way; that can easily slow down your code.

Comment: agreed. I'd like to have something I can just apply by id ideally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want in one line:

```
dt[, myVals := rowSums(cbind(var1, shift(var2)), na.rm=TRUE), by=id]
dt
   id time var1 var2 myVals
1: AT 2001    1   NA      1
2: AT 2002    2    1      2
3: AT 2003    3    2      4
4: DE 2001    4    3      4
5: DE 2002    5   NA      8
6: DE 2003    6    8      6
```

The two variables of interest are put into `cbind` which is used to feed `rowSums` and NAs are dropped as in your code.

Comment: yes, thanks! Is there any reason to prefer cbind over setDT or the other way around (compare to akrun)

Comment: As I understand it, `rowSums` is a base R function that takes array-like objects as inputs. It will do conversion of a data.frame (or data.table) to a matrix if given such an object, so by feeding it a matrix at the start, this conversion is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums`

```
 data[, goalmessy := rowSums(setDT(.(var1, shift(var2))), na.rm = TRUE), by = id]
```